# Game crafting system logic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello fellow programmers. I have a question about crafting for a game in Unity3d, but it's more about C#.
I have a class called Item(it only contains string itemname, and int value). I also have a class called crafting recipe with a item called output, and here is one thing im not sure about, should I use a dictionary or generic list for the inputitems variable. Also, when making my inventory class do I use a dictionary or generic list for the items in the inventory.

Although here is the part I really need help on(I've tried before but not succeeded), how do I make it that when I craft, It checks through my Items in the inventory and if I have all the items needed in the inventory(so checks if I have all the inputitems in my inventory), it will remove them, and add the output item to the inventory. Also I use C#.
Thanks :)

Edit Here is an Example::

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {
//Should this be a dictionary.
    public List<Item> InventoryList = new List<Item>();

}

public class Item{

    public string ItemName;
    public int ItemValue;

}

public class CraftingItem{
//Should I make this a dictionary or leave it?
    public List<Item> InputItems = new List<Item>();
    public Item Output;
}
```

Comment: Some code to demonstrate what you're doing might help us out.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in the following way:

```
class Program
{
    public class Inventory : List<Item>
    {
        public int Weight { get; set; } 
        // some other properties 
    }

    public class Item : IEquatable<Item>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Item other)
        {
            return this.Name == other.Name; 
        }
    }

    public class ItemsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
    {
        public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
        {
            if (x.Name.Equals(y.Name)) return true;

            return false; 
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
        {
            return 0; 
        }
    }

    public class CraftingRecipe
    {
        private List<Item> _recipe;
        private Item _outputItem; 

        public CraftingRecipe(List<Item> recipe, Item outputItem)
        {
            _recipe = recipe;
            _outputItem = outputItem; 
        }

        public Item CraftItem(Inventory inventory)
        {
            if (_recipe == null)
            {
                //throw some ex
            }

            var commonItems = _recipe.Intersect(inventory, new ItemsComparer()).ToList();
            if (commonItems.Count == _recipe.Count)
            {
                inventory.RemoveAll(x => commonItems.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name));
                return _outputItem; 
            }

            return null; 
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Item> recipeItems = new List<Item>() 
            { 
                new Item { Name = "Sword" } ,
                new Item { Name = "Magic Stone" }
            }; 
        Item outputItem = new Item() { Name ="Super magic sword" }; 

        Inventory inventory = new Inventory() 
            { 
                new Item { Name = "Sword" } ,
                new Item { Name = "Ring" },
                new Item { Name = "Magic Stone" }
            };

        CraftingRecipe craftingRecipe =
            new CraftingRecipe(recipeItems, outputItem);

        var newlyCraftedItem = craftingRecipe.CraftItem(inventory);

        if (newlyCraftedItem != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newlyCraftedItem.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your item has not been crafted"); 
        }
        Console.Read(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Also could you just type a line of code to show me how to craft the item, also, Inventory script has to inherit from monobehavior.

Comment: I have updated the code and placed the logic for crafting and item (CraftItem method) - now it removes the items from inventory (which were used to craft an item) and returns the crafted item.